# Toast inside OnPostExecute() not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-toast

I'm making this call from the main_activity

```
Intent createAccount = new Intent(mainact_Context,Register_activity.class);
startActivity(createAccount);
```

This is the activity that calls the `AsyncTask`:

```
public class Register_activity extends Activity {
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_activity);
        Button RegButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Regbutton);

        RegButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RegisterWithServer regser = new RegisterWithServer(context);
                regser.execute();

            }

        });

        setupActionBar();
    }
}
```

Inside my Async activity, I have this:

```
public class RegisterWithServer extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {

    Context con;

    public RegisterWithServer(Context context)
    {
        con = context;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //this code gets executed perfectly
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        /*I tried doing something with the context and the result string here and it worked too.*/
        Toast.makeText(con, result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The `doInBackground()` part gets executed perfectly. The `onPostExecute()` part gets called but the `Toast` is not showing. Can anyone spot anything?

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); or  Toast.makeText(classname.this, result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();or Context con=this;//initialize this first

Comment: are you sure the activity is still alive when the task ends?

Comment: Instead of v.getContext() try Register_activity.this

Comment: @greenapps: Couldn't do that, it says "No enclosing instance of the type Register_activity is accessible in scope"

Comment: @Mario Lenci: I'm sure that the activity is alive cuz I tried changing the text of a button inside Register_activity from the same onpostexecute method and it worked.

Comment: @Sania: Can't do that cuz RegisterWithServer is an AsyncTask not an Activity. Toast.MakeText accepts only the context of an activity as its first argument.

Comment: "Inside my Async activity, I have this". Where is that? Put the asynctask in Register_activity.

Comment: Context con=this; then put this line atleast and i am telling about your Activity(main) not AsyncTAsk class

Comment: @Sania: tried your solution, didn't work either. I have edited my question to reflect the change that I did.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your Toast message inside of implementing runOnUI() thread in order to show the alert in the proper application thread, try it and will work. Regards